# Xamarin Android: How to authenticate to dynamics

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, microsoft-dynamics

I've found a documentation of how authenticate to dynamics but was for xamarin forms and have tested it worked out.

But now I want to authenticate to dynamics properly on xamarin Android without using xamarin forms library

Is there a way to authenticate to dynamics that is made for xamarin Android that I don't need to use the xamarin forms way to authenticate?

The documentation of how to authenticate to dynamics using xamarin forms
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-active-directory-login-in-xamarin-forms/

My authenticator class:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Apontamento_Despesa.Authenticator))]

public class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
{
    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
        var uri = new Uri(returnUri);

        var platformParams = new PlatformParameters((Activity)Forms.Context);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
        return authResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is quite easy actually all you have to do is remove all the `Xamarin.Forms` related code from the above method and it should work for you, something like this should work

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri, Activity activity)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
    var uri = new Uri(returnUri);

    var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(activity);
    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
    return authResult;
}
```

Where Activity is the calling activity.

Comment: I got an exception the execution be at break  mode

Comment: What does that exeption say?

Comment: public class Authenticator : IAuthenticator

Comment: the error is:  'Authenticator does not implement interface menbe ' IAuthenticator.Authenticate(string,string,string,string)'

Comment: I was abble to fix that problem, but now the app is on break mode because the activity has a null value.

Comment: I do not think the IAutenticator Interface is required at all since you are using Xamarin Android!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
[assembly: Xamarin.forms.Dependency(typeof(App11.Authenticator))]
```

DependencyService is usually used in Xamarin.Forms,but now you are Xamarin.Android project.you dont need IAuthenticator and Authenticator class ,you could write the method in your activity directly like (I'm not sure your Authenticate method works，only for the error of Dependency):

```
private  async void Authenticate()
{
    string Nome_Usuario = "taniguchi.sales@ax4b.com";
    string clientId = "2b121ed5-9fe6-4ddf-bdea-9bbe8cd37bd0";
    string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ax4b.com";
    string returnUri = "https://ax4bdev.crm2.dynamics.com";
    string graphResourceUri = "https://ax4bdev.crm2.dynamics.com";
    var data = await Authenticate(authority, graphResourceUri, clientId, returnUri);

}

private async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
    var uri = new Uri(returnUri);

    var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(this);
    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
    return authResult;
}
```